# How can I change CharacterSpacing (Kerning) of a .Net Maui Entry control?

Tags: maui

I'm trying to set the character spacing (kerning) of an Entry control in .Net Maui 8. I've setup the `Entry` control as following:

```
<Entry MaxLength="6"
       x:Name="dataEntry"
       HorizontalOptions="Fill"
       Keyboard="Numeric"
       Style="{StaticResource Typography1}"
       TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
       WidthRequest="275.0"
       CharacterSpacing="3.0">
       <Entry.FontSize>
         <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="18" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="22" />
         </OnPlatform>
       </Entry.FontSize>
</Entry>
```

However, CharacterSpacing seems to have not effect on the space between characters inside Entry control. Doesn't matter now small or larger I setup the CharacterSpacing value. I've tried up to `CharacterSpacing="50.0"`. I want each character in the input box to be 50 units apart.

I've tried it with a `Label` and it works fine. It is in the `Entry` control it doesn't work.

```
<Label WidthRequest="400"
    Text="Hello"
    CharacterSpacing="40" />
```

Comment: Try searching through the open issues if you find a match:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues

Answer (score 0):

I tested on my side and it worked well. I tested on both Android and Windows platforms. Please check the style you used in this entry.

```
 <Entry MaxLength="6"
  x:Name="dataEntry"
  HorizontalOptions="Fill"
  Keyboard="Numeric"
  WidthRequest="275.0"
  CharacterSpacing="30.0">
     <Entry.FontSize>
         <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
             <On Platform="Android" Value="18" />
             <On Platform="iOS" Value="22" />
         </OnPlatform>
     </Entry.FontSize>
 </Entry>
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. Did you use Maui 8 or 9 preview?

Comment: I am using the .net8.

Answer (score 0):

**Set character spacing**:
Character spacing can be applied to an Entry by setting the **CharacterSpacing** property to a double value:

XAML

<Entry ...
CharacterSpacing="10" />

The result is that characters in the text displayed by the Entry are spaced CharacterSpacing device-independent units apart.

**Note**

The CharacterSpacing property value is applied to the text displayed by the Text and Placeholder properties.

Source(microsoft document) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/entry?view=net-maui-8.0